# stepwise regression: Undefined function ' stepwiselm' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Tags: matlab, regression

I have one .txt file and I have converted it to first a table Ta(Ta=readtable（'xxx.txt'）) then an array Aa（Aa=table2array(Ta)）, the .txt file contains 220 rows and 12 cols, but the table and the array only have 219 rows and 1 col. Where did I do wrong?

Then when I tried to do stepwise regression I got error message: Undefined function ' stepwiselm' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

My coad was: mdl=stepwiselm(Aa)

In the .txt file, the first raw are texts e.g. elevation, hight, yields etc. I though I could use these names to define Predictor variables and Response variable. But since these names are lost in Aa, how should I write code for stepwise regression?Thanks!

Comment: I re-installed Matlab again so now I have statistics toolbox. I then created a matrix M forA-100spreg-raa01.txt and ran stepwise('M',10), since I want the 10th col be y.In the .txt the 10th col is 'yield' but all texts are not showing in M so I don't know how should I write e.g. use 'yield' as dependent variable i.e. response variable and 'DEM, grad, HI' as independent variables i.e.predictor variables.Aan I also want to calculated standard deviation of M, I wrote std('M'),but got ans=0. Any tips?Thanks!

Comment: I got stepwise regression result in a new window, everything looks find. But in command window, I got errors:Attempted to access R(1); index out of bounds because numel(R)=0.Error stepwisefit>stepcalc (line 279) Rrank = sum(abs(diag(R)) > tol*abs(R(1)));Error stepwisefit (line 146) [B,SE,PVAL,stats] = stepcalc(allx,y,in); Error stepwise>stepmain (line 110) [~,~,~,in,stats,nextstep] = ... Error stepwise>doscale (line 860) in = stepmain(X,y,in,F);Error while evaluating uimenu Callbac.

Comment: Difficult to say. It may have something to do with what you input to `stepwise`, maybe `y` should not be equal to columns of `X` (i.e. try `stepwise(M(:,1:9),M(:,10))`)? What does `M` look like anyway?

Comment: I got another idea that to create a dataset for stepwise:A = dataset('File','Araa06.txt'), M is converted from Araa06(first row texts), then I got 2 errors:'Misuse dataset/readFile (line 207) Variable lengths must all be the same'. 'Error dataset (line 351) a = readFile(a,fileArg,otherArgs)' Any idea why this happened?

Comment: @A.Klomp Now it says                                               'The number of variable names read from A-100spreg2-raa06a.txt does not match the number of data columns.  You may have specified the format string,delimiter, or the number of header lines incorrectly.
Error dataset (line 351)
a = readFile(a,fileArg,otherArgs)' But I do have 12 names for 12 cols, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
delim = ' '; 
nrhdr = 1; 
A = importdata('A-100spreg2-raa06a.txt', delim, nrhdr);
```

`A.data` will be your data, `A.textdata` your header. A ".txt" does not contain columns, so you need to specify a delimiter (I assumed a space). You can then use your A.data in your `stepwise` function.

As you indicated you wanted column 10 as `y`, and I assume others as `X`, use

```
stepwise(A.data(:,1:9),A.data(:,10))
```

I wouldn't use the headers for anything other than creating labels in figures.

Comment: Thanks!I copied the first row i.e. names of variables to 'A-100spreg2-raa06a.txt' and created a dataset A, and it worked, as does stepwise function. But why after I ran mdl = stepwiselm(A,'constant','ResponseVar','Yield','PredictorVars',{'DEM','HI','DAI2'}), I only got Pvalue for DEM and HI?

Comment: Excellent! Are you sure DAI2 is mentioned as such in your dataset object? Or maybe it doesn't like the 2 in the name? Just guessing here..

Comment: if I wrote mdl=stepwiselm(A,'interactions','ResponseVar','Yield','PredictorVars',{'DEM','HI','DAI2'}), then I got all predictor variables in the outpot, but it doesn't work with 'constant', I guess it is removed from the model coz it exceeds the threshol of entering/removing (0.15)? Or type 2 error?